# Mongo - Find a random document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with users. I want to find a random collection, except mine.

```
db.mycoll.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }])
```

This can return my document.

```
User.aggregate([
 { $match: { _id: { $nin: myID } } },
 { $sample: { size: 1 } }
])
```

Is this efficient for a really big collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stages of your aggregation pipeline:

```
{ $match: { _id: { $nin: myID } } }
```

[Pipeline Sequence Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#pipeline-sequence-optimization)

This will use the built-in index on _id.

```
{ $sample: { size: 1 } }
```

This will select a sample record from the result of $match stage.

This is expected to be efficient provided not a not large size myID array.

*Note:The inequality operator $nin is not very selective since it often matches a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a $nin query with an index may perform no better than a $nin query that must scan all documents in a collection*